# Testing Devise - Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find xpath "/html"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, factory-bot

I'm trying to test the login functionality of my website with RSpec, Capybara and Factory Girl. I always get the following error in the terminal but couldn't find any solution to this. When I use `save_and_open_page` I get a blank page. I hope someone knows what's wrong. Thanks!

Here is the `test output`

```
Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_text("Login successful.")
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find xpath "/html"
     # ./spec/features/navigation_spec.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is my `sometest_spec.rb` file with the corresponding lines:

```
require 'spec_helper'
include Warden::Test::Helpers

describe "User login" do
  it "log in normal user" do

    Warden.test_mode!

    user = create(:normal_user)
    user.confirmed_at = Time.now
    user.save
    login_as(user, scope: :user)

    expect(page).to have_text("Login successful.")

    logout(:user)
    Warden.test_reset!
  end
end
```

Here is my `factory_girl.rb` file

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

And the `factories.rb` file

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :normal_user, class: User do
    firstname "John"
    lastname "Doe"
    email "test@user.com"
    password "thepassword"
    admin false
  end
end
```

Comment: try using have_content instead of have_text ....not sure

Comment: No that't not fixing it. I'm successfully using have_text at other places as well. It seems like the login_as method doesn't have any redirect "impact".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out I have to manually `visit a_path` after the `login_as` to see the additional login page content.